# algorithm to print Degree sequence of graph from smallest to biggest

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Given a graph G=(V,E) in adjacency list presentation, The Degree Sequence problem is that of out-puting the nodes of V in order from smallest to biggest degree.  Given an algorithm to solve this problem with its running time.

This is what I have so far

Let's say we have this

```
A -> 1->2->3
B -> 1->2->3->4
C -> 1->2->3->4->5
D -> 1->2->3
E -> 1->2->3->4
```

This should print 3,3,4,4,5

To find this we have to iterate all the edges in A, then all the edges in B, and all the edges in C and so on

This will take V * E because we have V vertex with E edges, hense the complexity will be O(V*E).

Is this right? This is a practice Exam Problem. Can someone please help me or give me a hint on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Seems like there's a sorting step missing in your answer. And `E` is usually the total number of edges in the graph. But overall, I get the impression that you haven't quite presented the question the way it was presented in the exam.

Comment: @user3386109 Hey I just want to clarify.  So the complexity will be O(V*E) to find the total edges + O(n log n) to sort the result?  Thanks for your help.